# Integrating AWS Dragonfly with DynamoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I want to upload images to AWS S3 and want to use DynamoDB as backend for this functionality in Rails.

I am using [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-dragonfly/) application to upload the images and Need to have image data into DynamoDB

How can I connect and use DynamoDB with my Application?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ruby [AWS SDK Rails](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails) [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-rails) as described in [this AWS Ruby blog](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx18J68KPIUWMOX/Announcing-the-aws-sdk-rails-Gem#) post.